# Google Chrome radial gradient blinking

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I'm doing a website and I decided to use a gradient instead of image, but I encountered the problem in Google Chrome (v. 29.0.1547.65). The gradient blinks with the following code.

HTML:

```
<div class="blueline-top"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.blueline-top {
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    background: radial-gradient(50% 300px, circle, #157cda, #14426c);
    background: -webkit-radial-gradient(50% 300px, circle, #157cda, #14426c);
}
```

The demo: http://jsfiddle.net/DaZzz/BCBG8/1/

How to solve this issue? Has anybody encountered this before?

**UPD. 1:** I'm using Mac OS 10.8.4. In Safari this code works perfectly fine.

**UPD. 2:** Faced the same issue in Opera 17.0.1241.18.

Comment: I am using the same version of Chrome and I do not see blinking in the example you provided.

Comment: Is this Mac related? Provide more info.

Comment: Question is updated. Yes, I'm using Mac OS.

Comment: My partner uses mac to design and test the websites we develop.  Frequently he sees this kind of issues in elements with css3 effects. I don't know how to solve them, actually I don't care very much. Try adding  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0); to force gpu acceleration.

Comment: No problem here: 29.0.1547.66/Windows. It should be reported on http://crbug.com

Answer (score 1):

This is probably due to pixel walking/inversion issues.  It's cause is likely due to voltages not being correct across the LCD screen.  I don't know a lot about it, but there are some very good tests to see if your monitor has it here:

http://www.lagom.nl/lcd-test/inversion.php#invpattern

Answer (score 0):

Go to the menu and unmark this option: settings -> show advanced options -> Use hardware acceleration when available.

If the problem stops occurying it might be a few things:

1. Your video card is going bad.
2. You have a video card driver bug.
3. There is a bug in your version of chrome for your OS.

1 and can be ruled out by testing in another machine. 2 can be ruled out by upgrading and/or downgrading your driver. 3 can be ruled out by upgrading or downgrading your chrome version.

From my experience 1. is not as unreasonable as you might think.